# How to query composite element of collection? (cannot create element join for a collection of non-entities)

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I have a class Goods

```
    <class name="Goods">
        ...
    <map name="names" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <key not-null="true" />
        <map-key column="LANGUAGE_CODE" type="language" length="2"/>
        <composite-element class="Goods$Names">
            <property name="name" not-null="true" type="text"/>
            <property name="description" type="text"/>
        </composite-element>
    </map>

    ...

</class>
```

The problem arises when I try to search Goods by name like this:

```
session.createQuery("select g from Goods g where g.names[:lang].name = 'Some goods name'")


javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create element join for a collection of non-entities!
```

Is it really impossible to do so with Hibernate?
Do I really need to make goods name an entity with it's own id? 
Any solution?

Comment: Why not to make it as entity?

Comment: I dont want entity because I dont want an extra id column. So my first aproach was create entity with composite id. But finally i understand how i have to create my query. So this query simply works: select g from Goods g join g.names names with index(names) = :lang where names.name='some goods names'

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to create the entity class with composite key, then you have to go for inner class in java*, If you are making the entities in hibernate than you have to maintain the relationship(like many to many, one to many, one to one, many to one) between your entities, and then Hibernate have the functionality to perform the join internally, you need not to perform that on you own, this is the whole hint from my side,please try it even this makes your design good understandable to others.

Comment: If this answers solves your problem, please approve it so it help others as well